# Some IMAP folders not showing in Roundcube after email server migration

Tags: postfix, imap, maildir

I'm in the process of moving email servers and am having some with nested IMAP folder.
The new server uses a mailinabox installation and is based on postfix, just as the old email server was.

I thus copied over the entire contents of the email folders, preserving timestamps and all the files, and just moved the maildirs over to the new server.

A similar operation had been conducted years ago as well, from yet another postfix based email server.

Now what's happening is that in the new server only some of the IMAP folders are showing up in roundcube, and I can't seem to be able to figure out what exactly is causing this.
There are some email users that have a large amount of nested folders, and sometimes the folders don't show up at all, or sometimes a subset of folders shows up.
It doesn't seem to be correlated with folder names, as there are no funny charachters used in naming the folders or similar.

I've checked file permissions and they are all correct.

Ideas?

Comment: Postfix is irrelevant in that matter, you need to be concerned with the IMAP component of your setup.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific @Sven ? What exactly would you look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Roundcube does not subscribe to all IMAP folders by default.
Simply resubscribing to the folder from roundcube fixed the issue.